# jquery hide method only hides div for a second but then div reappears automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, html

I seem to have same issue as the one I posted before. I want to hide all the divs that are there by default and only display one. Then the user can click on a side tab to display another. Problem is the divs are only hidden for a second after page loads but reappear soon after. This is code that's suppose to hide the divs of the page and only display the div with id of "pple":

```
$("a#link2").click(function(){$("#content > div").hide(); $("#pple").show();});

markup:

   home.html:                                           
<li><a href="about.html" id="link2">About</a></li>

about.html:
<div id="content">
 <div class="tabContent" id="pple">
<p>
    Content
<p> 
   </div>

    <div class="tabContent" id="serv">

<p>
    Content
</p>    
  </div>

  <div class="tabContent" id="sol">     

<p>
    Content
</p>    
  </div>            
</div>
```

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Is *this* page `about.html`? It looks like your code is reloading the page, unless you're preventing the anchor from being followed in additional code you haven't posted.

Comment: no the link is not on about.html. The link belongs to home.html.

Answer (score 9):

You need to `return false;` on your handler for the `<a>` element.

This is because the default behavior of the `<a>` element is occurring and reloading the page, so you need to disable that behavior.

```
$("a#link2").click(function(){
    $("#content > div").hide(); 
    $("#pple").show();
    return false;  // Will prevent default behavior
                   //   but it also prevents event bubbling
});
```

Alternatively, you could call `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("a#link2").click(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevents the default behavior
                             //    and event bubbling is still intact
    $("#content > div").hide(); 
    $("#pple").show();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: The problem is there are two different urls, one is the default home page: home.html and the other is about.html, so return false will prevent it going to the next page when you click on the link. Also, event.preventDefault() doesn't do anything at all - when I click the link, it takes me to the next page but doesn't hide anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent default after the divs are hide
 so you can do 
       `...function(event)
         event.preventDefault()...`

Comment: Thanks Sam, event.preventDefault() stops div to reappear again. You saved my time as i had the same problem while clicking a button. Thanks.